# How to set the value of JFXcombobox without using index?

Tags: java, observablelist

How to set the value of combobox from the elements present in that combobox in java/javafx. This is the code what i have done till now.

```
package LetMeTest;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections; 
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class TryController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private JFXComboBox<?> cb;
@FXML
private JFXButton btnGet;
@FXML
private JFXButton btnSet;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{

    ObservableList oo=FXCollections.observableArrayList("b","a");
    cb.setItems(oo);


}       

@FXML
private void doGetItem(ActionEvent event) 
{
    System.out.println("Selected Item="+cb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

}

@FXML
private void doSetItem(ActionEvent event) 
{

    cb.setValue("b");

}

}
```

I am trying to do it using ObservableList. Tell me there is any other possibility to do it.

Comment: What do ya mean ?